# Mass assigning nested models in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I have a model called Tournament:

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :venue
  belongs_to :tier                                                                               
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tournament_directors, :class_name => "User"  

  ...
end
```

I want to have a edit tournament view where users can add tournament directors to a tournament by typing a user's name in a text field and clicking an add button using javascript.  I also want to have remove links that will remove a user using javascript.

I watched [a RailsCast for Nested Model Forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) but in the video they are actually creating and destroying the nested model (which in this case would be a user).  How can I use Rails to handle the assigned users to a tournament through form elements without creating and destroying users?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at one of Ryans more recent screencasts:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised

It should be a perfect example for what you're after.